# How to debug random cucumber failures?

Tags: javascript, ruby, debugging, cucumber

I'm stuck with an issue with a cucumber test suite and I can't think of any way of debugging it.

We have a pretty sizeable suit of cucumber features, all of them pass on the development machines. The problem is a couple of scenarios are failing when we run the whole cucumber suite on our ci server, and running them individually makes them pass and fail (apparently) randomly when the scenario tries to fill a form (that apparently isn't on the page). Because of the random failures I thought it was a timing problem with an ajax request, but that doesn't seem to be the case, because adding really big sleep (tried everything from 1 to 60 secs) doesn't change anything. This scenario is even more fun because there's another 3 scenearios running the same steps that are failing on the first one in the same order, and these pass except if I delete the first scenario, in which case the first one to run those steps is the one that fails.

Is there any tricks to debug this sort of weirdness on cucumber? features (keep in mind these scenarios always pass on the dev machines, the problem is in the ci server).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but that title is hilarious out of context. XD

Answer (score 0):

I've also had the opportunity to debug intermittent test failures that only reproduce on CI. In my experience the problem always boiled down to few basic causes:

1. Race conditions in the front-end. For example, enabling a form for input before an xhr callback adds default values.
2. "Optimistic" writes from the front-end. Sometimes a front-end engineer makes an action involving a PUT/POST request more responsive by ignoring the result. In this case, there's no way to get Cucumber to wait until the request has completed, so a test against the state change in the database will have a race with the application.
3. Requests to resources that aren't available in the test fixture. For example, requests to 3rd party APIs might be blocked from CI. Sometimes URLs are not constructed correctly in the test environment, particularly when they are built "by hand", instead of using Rails helpers.

Intermittent Cucumber failures are always challenging to debug. Don't give up! It's worth the effort to figure out how to build a testable, race-free front-end. You can use capybara-webkit to debug the CI-only failures. Get the javascript console output to printed out on CI, and then you can add prints to your javascript to trace its state up to the point of test failure. You can also hack capybara-webkit to print out information about requests made by the front-end. Here is an example: https://github.com/joshuanapoli/capybara-webkit/commit/96b645073f7b099196c5d3da4653606e98a453e4

Comment: I tried changing the driver to capybara-webkit (we were using poltergeist before) and the features that were intermittently failing before don't fail anymore. I'm assuming this must be a bug on poltergeist, but I can't quite figure out what's going on. Thanks for the tips though, I will watch out for that sort of things.