# Cucumber tests fail randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber, capybara

I have some Cucumber Scenario that are failing randomly both on local machine and Codeship (for Continuous Delivery). Running them individually or all together makes no difference, still pass and fail with no (identified) reason.

In detail, looks like Capybara is unable to find an element on the page after the 'Continue to next page' is clicked. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693683/cucumber-capybara-tests-fail-randomly-under-phantomjs) I've updated the `default_wait_time` to 10 seconds and even tried to put some `sleep()` with no success.

I've also seen that somebody had a similar situation (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336218/how-to-debug-random-cucumber-failures)) and fixed updating the capybara-webkit. So I've updated cucumber, selenium and poltergeist gem (working in Ruby) but that didn't fix the problem either.

It's worth mentioning that last time we pushed code in production **these tests were passing correctly**, both locally and on Codeship. No other release has been made after that so they started to fail while the code was already pushed in production. We explored some possible link with not-updated dates but looks like is all ok on that front.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Environment: Ruby on Rails 2.0.0p598, Capybara 2.6.0, Cucumber 1.3.20, Cucumber-rails 1.4.2, poltergeist 1.8.1, selenium-webdriver 2.49

__

EXAMPLES OF CODE FAILING:

```
@vcr_cassette #to fake API call
Scenario: User should be able to complete the last step of the application
  When I complete the application up to step 5 
  Then I should read "Step 6" #FAILS HERE
  When I fill application step 6
  And I click on "Submit your application"
  Then I should read "Congratulations! You have finished your application."

@vcr_cassette #to fake API call
Scenario: User should be able to complete the application
   When I complete the application up to step 6 #FAILS HERE
   Then I should read "Congratulations! You have finished your application."
```

Capybara fails to read 'Step 6'

Comment: What is the simplest example of code that is failing?

Comment: I would suggest you to use background and very all preconditions are there. Add code

Comment: What are the definitions of your "I complete the application..." and "I should read ..." steps - those would be the actual commands that Capybara runs